# Android Home Screen shortcut remove Listener?

Tags: android, shortcut

There is a question, how can I monitor the shortcut at Home Screen removed?

"com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" can delete shortcut in application, but that not what I mean.
I mean is not programmatically, but by User.

So if there exist any listener or event can help to monitor the shortcut be removed?

Answer (score 1):

No. Home screens do not have offer shortcuts, let alone advise you of when users themselves add or remove such shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to monitor the shortcut removing and adding, or we can monitor removing shortcut and readd it to home screen. That's terrible~~~